# Commerce- How to add a product image on a product display to the shopping cart summary view

Tags: commerce

I have two products on my site that are named similarly but easily distinguished by their images.  Users sometimes buy the wrong one by mistake, so I want to put the product image on the **Shopping cart summary view**.  By default, this view can be used to add fields of products.

My product images, however, are on the **Product display** content type.  Though the **Product display** has a product reference to **Products**, there seems to be no way to get the reverse of that relationship (in other words, to get the **Product Display** from the **Product**).

There aren't too many products, so I thought about just adding an image field to **Product** as well and duplicating all the data, but that is definitely a maintenance problem down the line.  Is there a way to get the image on the **Product Display** with just the **Product** in Views without duplicating data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it by adding two relationships. First add *Commerce Line item: Referenced products*

[image: referenced products]

and then that allows you to add *Commerce Product: Referencing Node*.

[image: referencing node]

From there you should be able to add and reference fields from your display node.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick-- it was called *Commerce Product: Referencing Content* on my site, but otherwise everything was as you described.